# angular ng-click to change class on click

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to remove all classes "**fa-3x** " and change all classes to "**fa-lg**" and add a class called="**testClass**", when the user click on class **toggle-button**. is it possible to do it in angular? really appreciate. your help

I know in jquery it very simple using add class and removeClass. can someone show me How to do it in angular?

```
  <div ng-controller="MainContainerController" ng-Click="toggleClass()">
        <ul class="nav" >
            <li>
                <a class="toggle-button"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="Home" ng-class="ActiveMenu('Home')">
                   <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x"></i>
                   <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ng-class="ActiveMenu('Work')"> 
                   <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-3x"></i>
                   <span>Work </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="Music" ng-class="ActiveMenu('Music')">
                   <i class="fa fa-table fa-3x"></i>
                   <span>Scenario <br/>Music</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a ui-sref="faq">
                   <i class="fa fa-faq fa-3x"></i>                           
                   <span>Faq</span> 
                </a>
            </li>
       </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: I was going to recommend taking a look at `ng-class`, but you're already using that on a different element. That's the directive to use for dynamically setting classes based on model values.

Comment: look at this entry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460369/adding-and-removing-classes-in-angularjs-using-ng-click

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a function, I would recommend to use `ng-class="{class1:(someVariable=='Workbench')}
ng-class="{class2:(someVariable=='Music')}"`
While in function `toggleClass()` you can setup `someVariable` to 'Home', 'Workbench' etc.

Answer (score 0):

user can use ng-class directive

```
<div  ng-click="changeClass()">
    <p ng-class="{'clicked':clicked,'not-clicked':!clicked}">Test</p>
    <p ng-class="{'clicked':clicked,'not-clicked':!clicked}">Test</p>

</div>
$scope.changeClass = function(){

    $scope.clicked = true;

};
```