# How to add class name with the existing class name

Tags: angularjs

I am getting `classname` from server as `red`,`blue` or `green`. i trying to add that class with the element. but nothing happening.

any one correct me please?

here is my try:

```
    <span class="proStatus" ng-class="{activeApp.status}"> //class not adds
      {{activeApp.status}} //i am getting `blue` here.
   </span>
```

Answer (score 5):

just put as,

```
<span class="proStatus {{activeApp.status}}"> ...
```

or **MORE efficiently**

```
<span class="proStatus" ng-class="activeApp.status"> ....
```

here is the [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

it says you can bind a `scope` value as,

```
$scope.className = 'this-is-class-name';

<span class="proStatus" ng-class="className">
```

**Why use { } in ng-class**

if you want to apply a css class based on some condition like below,

```
<span class="proStatus" ng-class="{ 'className' : applyClass }">
```

css class `className` will apply to the `span` only when `applyClass` is sets to `true`

Comment: Yes, But some times we use only one `{` brace. `ng-class="{enabled: $index == 0}"` then why you use 2 `{{` brace here? what is the scenario use?

Comment: if you want to apply a class based on a some condition then you have to go with single braces, if not you can interpolate it inside the `class` or more efficiently in the `ng-class` as showed above.