# Suggest a way to fill up <md-icon> according to condition?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, material-design, angular-material

[image: Job add view]

I want to fill up the heart icon color to red when a condition is true otherwise it'l be as blank..
i have used material design as follow

```
<md-button class="md-icon-button md-primary" aria-label="Settings" ng-click="checkShortList(shortListLoad.id)">
   <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-favorite-outline"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

How to solve this context? i'm newbie to material design.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the [Angular Material Icons](https://klarsys.github.io/angular-material-icons/)

You can just change the class from `icon-favorite-outline` to `icon-favorite`

With angular you can use [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) to change a class based on a condition

**Edit**
On further research I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460369/adding-and-removing-classes-in-angularjs-using-ng-click) is perhaps a more elegant solution to changing class.

> You just need to bind a variable into the directive "ng-class" and
>   change it from the controller.

.