# removeClass alike logic in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
.. ng-repeat
<li ng-class="{'active':selIndex==$index}">
<span ng-click="selIndex=$index">click</span>
</li>
```

The problem with above code is, it doesn't reset all the li's class before adding active class to the clicked one. How to apply removeClass logic in angluarjs?

Comment: Hello, how is this different from your last question.

Comment: See if this helps [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460369/adding-and-removing-classes-in-angularjs-using-ng-click)

Comment: @Tushar it's different. I stuck halfway and can't proceed.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what is happening or not happening and what you expect instead...

Comment: **Typo**: `ng-click="selIndex = $index"` <-- Single `=`.

Comment: @Tushar your solution worked. Just that it will have multiple highlight if I keep clicking on other's li.

Comment: @deceze what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You don't actively remove a class in Angular. You tell Angular under which circumstances which class must be active, and it will figure it out. You do that with `ng-class`, as you do. If the condition is `true`, the class will be present on the element, else it won't. **Whenever any state changes, Angular recalculates all the classes for all the elements.** Classes will be removed by Angular as soon as the condition for it becomes `false`.

More likely your logic doesn't work somewhere. I wouldn't use `$index` for anything, since the index of any one item might change at any time. Rather use the data itself:

```
$scope.items = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];
$scope.activeItem = null;
$scope.selectItem = function (item) {
    $scope.activeItem = item;
}
```

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{ active: item.id == activeItem.id }">
    <span ng-click="selectItem(item)">
```

Using direct assignment inside `ng-click` directives can get tricky in terms of scope; using a function on the controller typically works without any issues.

Comment: this work like accordian. I want to have a button that can remove the acitive class.

Comment: Not that if it's difficult to put it on the controller e.g. the ng-repeat is nested inside another ng-repeat then you can use ng-init to create the 'activeItem' variable

Comment: @Jennifer then just set activeItem = null ...

Comment: @Jennifer No you don't want to remove classes. You want to *model your state on the `$scope`*, then set up your view to present that state accordingly. That means anyone should be able at any time to look at your `$scope` and get the idea what's currently going on **purely from the data present there.** Don't think in terms of adding or removing anything in the view "by hand" directly. – Most likely you want a button *that sets the current active item to `null`.*

Comment: what is the activeItem.id come from?

Comment: @Jennifer From the `item` passed to the `selectItem` function. Which is one of the `items`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to ng-repeat that creates a child scope for each iteration.

You should try the following :

```
<li ng-class="{'active':$parent.selIndex==$index}">
    <span ng-click="$parent.selIndex=$index">click</span>
</li>
```

If you have nested ng-repeat, it will become a hell to debug. I recomend you to use the controller as syntax : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21292408/1251861

Comment: the ng-click should have a single =