# ng-class can't apply css class to element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I have this div somewhere in my code.

```
<div ng-class="className" >{{className}}</div>
```

At some point I am calling `changeClass` function from an ng-click to change the class of this div.

```
     $scope.changeClass = function(){
          console.log($scope.className)
              if ($scope.className === "expand-icon")
                 $scope.className = "expand-icon.expanded";
              else
                 $scope.className = "expand-icon";
  };
```

I can see the class changes because of the console.log and also the {{className}} is outputed on the page. However the css class doesn't seem to be applied.

It's in fact a '+' sign that needs to turn into a '-' with an animation. Here's the css:

```
 /* + button */

.expand-icon {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  position: relative;
}
.expand-icon::before, .expand-icon::after {
  content: " ";
  width: 32px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transition: all 0.15s cubic-bezier(.42, 0, .58, 1);
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.expand-icon::before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}
.expand-icon::after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.expand-icon {
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  position: relative;
}
.expand-icon.expanded::before {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
}
.expand-icon.expanded::after {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

So the expand-icon is applied but expand-icon.expanded doesn't have any affect since I'm using this ng-class trick. Any idea why?

Comment: You should replace the dot with a space: `$scope.className = "expand-icon expanded";`

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460369/adding-and-removing-classes-in-angularjs-using-ng-click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace the dot with a space: `$scope.className = "expand-icon expanded";`

Or better, use the other notation of `ng-class`:

```
// probably rename it to something like $scope.toggleExpanded()
$scope.changeClass = function(){
    $scope.expanded = !$scope.expanded;
};
```

And in your html:

```
<div class="expand-icon"
     ng-class="{ expanded: expanded }">{{className}}</div>
```

This will apply your `expand-icon` class always, and the `expanded` class only when the `$scope.expanded` property is truthy.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-class="className"` is for expression. for example: `ng-class="{classNam:true}"`.

in this case you can just do like this: `class="{{className}}"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="{{className}}">{{className}}</div>
```