# Change Buttons when Clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Below is my HTML code with Bootstrap and Angular:

```
   <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" ng-click="buy(player)">{{history.indexOf(player)>=0?'REMOVE':'SELECT'}}</button>
```

When i click the button, the wording of the button changes from 'SELECT' to 'REMOVE'. However, what i want is the colour of the button to change so that it is the default colour when on 'SELECT' but the red "btn-danger" class when 'REMOVE'.

Is this possible?

Comment: simple change the class like you did with content, it's easy with angularjs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460369/adding-and-removing-classes-in-angularjs-using-ng-click

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! And it's really simple.

```
 <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" ng-class="{'btn-danger': history.indexOf(player) >= 0 }" ng-click="buy(player)">{{history.indexOf(player)>=0?'REMOVE':'SELECT'}}</button>
```

Note **ng-class** directive added to the button.