# Setting td class on click angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have **table** like this

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of createRange(seats.theatreDimension.rowNum)">
            <td [ngClass]="{'reserved': isReserved(row, seat)}" id={{row}}_{{seat}} (click)="selectSeat(row, seat)" *ngFor="let seat of createRange(seats.theatreDimension.seatNumInRow)">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to also set **td** class `'reserved'` on click.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: toggle based on a boolean property

Comment: or keep a multidimensional array to hold the state

Comment: Maybe this discussion will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460369/adding-and-removing-classes-in-angularjs-using-ng-click

Comment: I am using angular 2

Comment: @user184994 do you have some advice on this please?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<td [ngClass]="{'reserved': isReserved(row, seat)}" id={{row}}_{{seat}} @click="selectSeat(row, seat)" *ngFor="let seat of createRange(seats.theatreDimension.seatNumInRow)">
        </td>
```